# Swift barrier блокирование Work items

Tags: swift, асинхронность, очередь, concurrency

Из документации Apple:

async:  execute work: `work` The work item to be invoked on the queue.

barrier: Work items submitted prior to the barrier execute to completion, at which point the barrier work item executes.

Я ожидал, что барьер заблокирует второе замыкание(work item), пока не выполнится первое. Но в этом примере barrier, ничего не делает. Объясните в чем причина?

```
var map = Array<Int>()
let group = DispatchGroup()
let queue = DispatchQueue.global()

group.enter()
queue.async() {
    for _ in 1...10 {
        print(map)
    }
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
queue.async(flags:.barrier) {
    for index in 1...10 {
        map.append(index)
    }
    group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
    print("end")
})
```

В консоли:

```
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
var map = [Int]()
let group = DispatchGroup()
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "example", attributes: .concurrent)

group.enter()
queue.async() {
    for _ in 1...10 {
        print(map)
    }
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
queue.async(flags:.barrier) {
    for index in 1...10 {
        map.append(index)
        print(map)
    }
    group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
    print("end")
})
```

Comment: Спасибо! Дело в DispatchQueue.global. Из описания: Calls to the suspend(), resume(), and dispatch_set_context(_:_:) functions have no effect on the returned queues. Видимо дело в этом.

Comment: Правда остался вопрос. Зачем Apple разрешают применять async(flags:.barrier) к глобальной очереди, если barrier все равно не отработает?

Comment: Формально barrier срабатывает, но не так как ожидается. Позапускайте ваш пример, каждый раз он будет выдавать разные результаты. Чтобы он точно сработал, нужно создать очередь изоляции.

Comment: Пример будет выдавать разный результат и без барьера. Не совсем понимаю, что означает срабатывает формально. Где написано, чтобы сработал барьер, нужно писать очередь изоляции?

Comment: Use caution when using barriers in global background concurrent queues as these queues are shared resources. Using barriers in a custom serial queue is redundant as it already executes serially. Using barriers in custom concurrent queue is a great choice for handling thread safety in atomic or critical areas of code. https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2