# GCD Swift или как задать приоритет

Tags: swift

Всем привет! Есть два метода, которые выполняются асинхронно. По сути, они вдвоем подргружают большое кол-во данных + преобразуют из base64string в UIImage.
Один из этих методов должен быть в приоритете. То есть, сперва должен выполниться один, а потом уже другой. Либо они запустится в двоем, но приоритет на скорость будет у первого. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Добавить "приоритет"можно с помощь _DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)_ , а другой ваш метод закиньте в поток с меньшим приоритетом  _.userInitiated_ или _.utility_

Comment: Попробуйте использовать пример из моего ответа здесь: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1049227/swift-barrier-блокирование-work-items](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1049227/swift-barrier-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-work-items)